# remote assistance not allowing UAC prompt interaction with the box checked to allow

Tags: windows, uac, remote-assistance

I need to be able to connect up to customers computers and would like to use Remote Assistance, but I am unable to click on any UAC prompts, even though the user puts a check mark to allow me to click on the UAC prompts.

Here are the details:

- They send me an invite file.
- I start the session and they accept.
- I can see their desktop.
- I request control and they get a prompt to share control.
- They put a check in "Allow xxxxx to respond to User Account Control Prompts" and click Yes.
- Everything is fine until I get a UAC prompt.

I am unable to click on anything until the user clicks "yes". Isn't the point of that last box to prevent this? Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2):

You need to turn on a Group Policy setting and/or download a hotfix:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asklar/archive/2012/03/14/remote-assistance-and-uac-prompts.aspx

> However, in order for this to work properly in scenarios that prompt
>   for elevation (i.e. UAC prompt), you have to enable a certain group
>   policy:
>
> User Account Control: Allow UIAccess applications to prompt for
>   elevation without using the secure desktop
>
> What this will do is it will enable Remote Assistance to show the UAC
>   prompt on the user’s desktop, as opposed to the secure desktop. If you
>   don’t enable this, the user being helped (call him novice) will get
>   the prompt on his local machine – so the expert cannot interact with
>   it since RA will only remote out the user’s desktop. At that point,
>   the novice may not know what to do with it, and/or he may not have the
>   administrator password. So it is important that you enable this group
>   policy in order to have the UAC prompt show up in the user’s desktop
>   and have RA remote out this dialog to the expert’s machine.

Answer (score 1):

I recently created this PowerShell solution which can be used when need to open a Remote Assistance session and type in the elevated UAC credential that cannot be share with the end-user being assisted.

Technically you can run just the `Invoke-Command` and point it to the remote computer, and then ensure the `Set-ItemProperty` has the appropriate `1` or `0` value for "`PromptOnSecureDesktop`" to enable or disable.

I wanted to ensure that when I need to run `msra` in an elevated session, I can just execute the script and be assured the UAC secure desktop security is re-enabled automatically after the `msra` session has ended.

> **Essentially this will...**
>
> - prompt you for the computer name
> - disable the "UAC secure desktop" via the remote registry change and commands
> - start an `msra` session that works same way it works always works from here
> - enable the "UAC secure desktop" via the remote registry change and commands once the correlated `msra` instance ends
>
> **To use you only need to...**
>
> 1. Save the PowerShell script as a text document with a `.ps1` file name extension
> 2. Open a PowerShell command prompt and type (or paste) in the full script path and filename, and press <kbd>`Enter`</kbd>
> 3. Enter in the computer name of the computer you are connecting to with remote assistance and  press <kbd>`Enter`</kbd>.
> 4. When done with the remote assistance session, close the `mrsa` process if it's still running

**Tip:** Use the non-elevated "other/standard" method of `msra` most of the time, and only use this as-needed.

## PowerShell Script

```
$pc = Read-Host "Enter the remote computer name to disable secure desktop";

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pc -Scriptblock {
    Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" -Name "PromptOnSecureDesktop" -Value 0 -Force;
    };

$remoteAssist = "$Env:windir\system32\msra.exe";
Start-Process $remoteAssist "/offerra" -Wait;
Write-Host "Your Remote assist session has ended" -ForegroundColor Red;

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pc -Scriptblock {
    Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" -Name "PromptOnSecureDesktop"  -Value 1 -Force;
    };
```

**Execute Example**

*Note: Just paste in the full path script name and press enter.*

```
PS C:\Users\User> \\myserver.domain.com\sharename\folder\script\Elevate-RemoteAssist.ps1
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- > #### [User Account Control: Switch to the secure desktop when prompting for elevation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/user-account-control-switch-to-the-secure-desktop-when-prompting-for-elevation)
  >
  > The secure desktop presents the logon UI and restricts functionality
  >   and access to the system until the logon requirements are satisfied.
  >
  > The secure desktop’s primary difference from the user desktop is that
  >   only trusted processes running as `SYSTEM` are allowed to run here
  >   (that is, nothing is running at the user’s privilege level). The path
  >   to get to the secure desktop from the user desktop must also be
  >   trusted through the entire chain.
  >
  > #### Possible values
  >
  > - **Enabled**
  >
  >   - All elevation requests by default go to the secure desktop.
  > - **Disabled**
  >
  >   - All elevation requests go to the interactive user desktop.
  >
  > [source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/user-account-control-switch-to-the-secure-desktop-when-prompting-for-elevation)
- [Invoke-Command](https://ss64.com/ps/invoke-command.html)
- [Set-ItemProperty](https://ss64.com/ps/set-itemproperty.html)
- [Start-Process](https://ss64.com/ps/start-process.html)

  > ```
  >  -Wait
  >    Wait for the specified process to complete before accepting more input.
  >    This parameter suppresses the command  prompt or retains the window
  >    until the process completes
  > ```

Comment: @rerat - With this answer, you have control when to turn the feature off or on. With the GPO way, it's one or the other whereas with this solution I provided, you allow as-needed only and disallow when done per each allowed session or instance of RA. Don't need to elevate, then use the other/standard where no elevation if needed in the remote support session.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66920815/38108 I'm struggling (PowerShell is quite new to me) …